# Running a Curl Command from C#

Tags: c#, command-line

I'm trying to run a curl command from a C# program.  My code is below.  When I run the code below, I get an exception that the file is not found.  I want to be able to do this but I do not want to use a batch file as a parameter for the filename.  That is because the arguments for my curl command are variable based upon other conditions in the C# code.  My variable strCmdText has the arguments for the curl command (the source and destination files).  There are other examples of this on Stackoverflow, but they all use a batch file which I'm trying to avoid.

```
Process p = new Process();
p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
p.StartInfo.FileName = "C:\\Windows\\System32\\curl.exe";
p.StartInfo.Arguments = strCmdText;
p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
p.Start();
p.WaitForExit();
```

I changed my code to the following:

```
System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo p = new 
    System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo();
    p.UseShellExecute = true;
    p.WorkingDirectory = "C:\\Windows\\System32\\";
    p.FileName = "curl.exe";
    p.ErrorDialog = true;
    p.CreateNoWindow = true;
    System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(p);
```

From a DOS prompt, curl does exist in this directory.  But I still get the curl not found message.
Something has to be strange with the path here.  When I put a break point in though, and view the Environment class, System32 is in the path.

Comment: The $1M question... Are you sure that `C:\Windows\System32\curl.exe` exists? That would be a really strange place for it...

Comment: If you want to make an HTTP request it's far faster to use HttpClient and just make the call. You can find where `curl` is with `where curl`

Comment: Also, while `curl` can do a lot, do consider if what you're trying to do can't also be done with a simple application of `WebClient` (`.DownloadFile` etc.)

Comment: curl is at that location on my machine. I think the file not found is related to your arguments.

Comment: Can you please show us the value of `strCmdText`?

Comment: I know this is not the answer to your question, but there is no reason to curl in C#. Use `HttpClient` to make HTTP request. If you want to translate a particular curl command use this: https://curl.olsh.me/

Comment: BTW a program calling another calling another is what batch programs do. Are you sure you aren't trying to write a batch in C# after all?

Comment: Yes I have used where curl and this is where it is

Comment: @canton7 After googling a little, that actually seems to be a very normal place for it. (weirdly)

Comment: @MariusBancila  The people consuming our file have asked us to use curl.  Not sure why.  Is there another way to transfer this file to them?

Comment: So it does. TIL. That might be specific to a particular version of Windows though, so it's worth checking that it's definitely there on your machine

Comment: There is better option for you `HttpClient`

Comment: Note that for a 32-bit application (which a .NET application will run as, if "prefer 32-bit" has been checked) `\Windows\System32` will be transparently mapped to `\Windows\SysWOW64`, where curl most likely does not live. The system directory is a very poor choice for user-supplied binaries, for this and other reasons.

Comment: When I run the following command     System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("CMD.exe", strCmdText)   it seems to work.  I put the curl in front of the arguments for it though.  The only reason I tried the other method is because I want program execution to pause while the file is uploading.

Comment: `cmd` on 64-bit Windows is a 64-bit application, so it would find curl where it expects to. For fun, try `p.StartInfo.FileName = @"C:\Windows\Sysnative\curl.exe"`. Alternatively (and better) compile the app explicitly as 64-bit.

Comment: Thanks @JeroenMostert  This was the solution to the problem!  SO does not allow me to mark your comment as the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Curl is available at the location: `C:\Windows\System32\curl.exe`

That only leaves the source file to be the culprit of a "File not found" issue.

As you're launching curl through a process, ensure that your paths are escaped properly in your startup arguments.

Alternatively, you could launch curl through cmd (through a process), you can try with the following, changing the command-line arguments from `--help` to suit your desired action.

```
string script = $"\"C:\\Windows\\System32\\curl.exe\" --help";

Process process = new Process()
{
    StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo()
    {
        FileName = "cmd",
        Arguments = script
    }
};

process.Start();
```

Please note that this is in principle, essentially using a batch file as it's just throwing some commands into a cmd.

Comment: Interesting, the actual error text is  "The system cannot find the file specified".  It seems like this exception is coming from the C# library.  If it was coming from the curl because the source file is not there, I'm thinking it would have been formatted differently since I feel like I've seen this message before from C#.

Comment: @Carl Areyou absolutely sure you have curl at the stated location then, on the active development machine? Try putting `C:\Windows\System32\curl.exe` into a regular cmd, and see if curl actually launches.

Comment: Yes it does launch from a command prompt.  The entire command works perfectly fine from the command prompt also; send the file just like it should

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same problem. Just delete curl.exe from System32 and place it on another folder (dont't forget the dependences, dlls, etc.).

Then in the line

```
p.StartInfo.FileName = "C:\\Windows\\System32\\curl.exe";
```

Overwrite `"C:\\Windows\\System32\\curl.exe"` to `"C:\\NEW PATH\\curl.exe"`.

Note: You MUST delete it from System32. If you just copy to the new location it will still don't work.